# How can I rewrite an "edit" operations link in Views?

Tags: views, 8

On Drupal 8, I'm trying to modify `/admin/people` to have the **edit** button read  **edit username** instead of **edit**.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Under fields, add the **User ID**.  Select *Exclude from display* and choose *Unformatted* for the **Formatter**.
2. Under fields, add **User Name** again.  Uncheck *display as link*.  Under **Administrative Title**, you can add something descriptive like `user name (no link)` so that you can remember what this is for.
3. Rearrange the fields so that **User ID** and the second **User Name** fields are at the top.
4. Click **User: Operation Links** under **Fields**.  Under **Rewrite results**, input the following for the text: `<a href="/user/{{ uid }}/edit">edit {{ name_1 }}</a>`

This makes a plain link instead of a button.  I imagine there is a more efficient way to do this, but this is the best I could come up with for now.